# Java Swing GUI freezes after boutton pressed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, thread-safety

I'm a newbie in java, and i"m trying to makge a simple GUI that will allow once a button clicked, to execute a .bat file and display the outpus in a `JTextPane`.
But once the button is pressed (The .bat file is excecuted), the whole GUI freezes, even after all the commands of the .bat file are excecuted.
I made some searchs and i've been told to create another thread in which the action on the bat file will be process, and i don't know how to do it.
This is my code :

```
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.casys.appletloader;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author ADMIN
 */
public class View1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form View1
     */
    public View1() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        fileButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        installBoutton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        listBoutton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        apduOutput = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu4 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem4 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenuItem2.setText("jMenuItem2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Application Loader - Casys Technology");
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(693, 492));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(693, 492));
        setResizable(false);

        fileButton.setText("Choose File...");
        fileButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                fileButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        installBoutton.setText("Install Applet");
        installBoutton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                installBouttonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        listBoutton.setText("List applets");
        listBoutton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                listBouttonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("File Name");

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(apduOutput);

        jMenu1.setText("Instaling Applet");
        jMenu1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenu1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Encoding");
        jMenu2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenu2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_E, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem1.setText("Encode");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu2.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        jMenu3.setText("APDU");
        jMenu3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenu3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jMenuItem3.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_P, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem3.setText("Excecute an APDU command");
        jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu3.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);

        jMenu4.setText("About");
        jMenu4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenu4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jMenuItem4.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_B, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem4.setText("About the program");
        jMenu4.add(jMenuItem4);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu4);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 216, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(237, 237, 237))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(119, 119, 119)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 270, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(installBoutton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(fileButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(listBoutton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap(56, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(fileButton)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(installBoutton)
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(listBoutton)
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 241, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void fileButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        new javax.swing.JFileChooser().setVisible(true);
    }                                          

    private void listBouttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jMenu4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void jMenu2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        //  new encoding_view().setVisible(true);
    }                                      

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        new encoding_view().setVisible(true);
    }                                          

    private void jMenu3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    }                                      

    private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        new apdu_view().setVisible(true);

    }                                          

    private void jMenu1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void installBouttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c C:\\Java\\commandes_applet\\delete.bat");
            InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
            int i = 0;
            while ((i = is.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) i);
                 apduOutput.setText(String.valueOf((char) i));
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.out.println(ioException.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioException);
        }

       /* try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }*/


    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new View1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextPane apduOutput;
    private javax.swing.JButton fileButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton installBoutton;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JButton listBoutton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is the code of the listener of the boutton :

````
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c C:\\Java\\commandes_applet\\delete.bat");
            InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
            int i = 0;
            while ((i = is.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) i);
                 apduOutput.setText(String.valueOf((char) i));
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.out.println(ioException.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioException);
        }

       /* try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }*/


    } ```



I'm using the NetBeans GUI drag and drop feature to make the UI.
````

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: When posting here, post code that has been stripped down to the absolute minimum needed to show your issue. We do not need or want to crawl through your entire app. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Stop using a GUI builder.  You're learning the GUI builder, not Swing.  The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will take you through the steps.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks. The real problem was with my .bat file and i solved it.